# remove timestamp from string that has date & time - c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string `"1/15/2017 12:00:00 AM"`.  I would like to remove timestamp from it.

I tried :

```
string str = "1/15/2017 12:00:00 AM"
str  = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

but this throws an error saying that it is not the right dateformat.

It does work if the string is `"11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM"` - but does not work if the string looks like `"1/15/2017 12:00:00 AM"` (m/d/yyy timestamp)

Comment: Try this str = DateTime.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")

Comment: `string dateOnly = timestamp.Split()[0];`

Comment: mm for minutes, MM is for months, case matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string is always going to be in the format you showed (date - blank space - time) you could simply do:

```
String dateTime = "1/15/2017 12:00:00 AM";
int index = dateTime.indexOf(" "); // gets index of first occurrence of blank space, which in this case separates the date from the time.
dateTime = dateTime.subString(0, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove `AM`?

Like this:

```
string str = "1/15/2017 12:00:00 AM";
str = str.Replace("AM","");
var time = Convert.ToDateTime(str);// 2017/1/15 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is in proper date format then you can try to convert in `DateTime` and then get only date from `DateTime` by using `ToShortDateString()`.

```
  string str = "1/15/2017 12:00:00 AM";
  DateTime dateStr = Convert.ToDateTime(str);
  string DateOnly = dateStr.ToShortDateString();
```